# How to update/insert by escape null properties? I using active record of CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter

I use active record of CodeIgniter, i face a problem:

1. i have one class in library :

   class TblUser{

   ```
     var $id = null;
     var $name = null;
     var $age = null;
   ```

   }
2. in model i have one class:

   ```
   class Task_m extends CI_Model {

       function add(){

          //Assume that i already success include class TblUser so i start instean

         $myTableUser = new TblUser ();
         $myTableUser->id = 1;
         $myTableUser->name = 'Foo';
         $myTableUser->age = 20;
         $this->db->insert('tbl_user',$myTableUser);
         // Assume that success add to database
       }
       function update($id,$name){

          //Assume that i already success include class TblUser so i start instean

         $myTableUser = new TblUser ();
         $myTableUser->name = $name;

         $this->db->where('id', $id);
         $this->db->update('tbl_user',$myTableUser); 
         // Assume that success add to database
       }


       /* problem 
        * i call function : update(1,'titi');
        * in database record will update like below:
        *  ----------------
        *  |id | name | age | 
        *   ----------------
        *  |null| titi| null|
        *  -----------------
        * I don't want null value, my wish if any property $myTableUser is null should be refuse.
        */






   }
   ```

For this mention i want use class pass to active record function but for any property contain with null value should be refuse. (similar  joomla  insteance table)

Answer (score 1):

the way you wrote the class as follows, its been quite obvious that it will take null values if its not provided.

```
class TblUser{

  var $id = null;
  var $name = null;
  var $age = null;
}
```

then you have two solutions

1. in `update()` function you initialize your object to `$myTableUser->id = $id`;
2. in table add column level constraints called `NOT NULL` so that it will throw exception if you are inserting `null` value.

Comment: first solution is best.. just add one line `$myTableUser->id = $id` after `$myTableUser->name = $name;`.. this is simplest solution :)

Comment: how about field "age"? in here just example, but truely we will have many properties that why i want class property assigned null is escape when action on database, like joomla instance table of component.

Comment: huh.. we have 2 solutions again.. 
1. make a database call to get that row and get the data and assign that data to the object variables respectively. and just update those object variable which needs to be updated
2. custom query.. as follows
`$this->db->where('id', $id);
$this->db->update('tbl_user',array('name' => $name));`